# api-gateway service unavailable due to time out, even returning result in less than 30 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I am using ECS service and calling via api-gateway. I know api-gateway limit to get back response within 30 seconds otherwise it will give error service unavailable.
to resolve this, I am using step function map state and passing my input in batches so api-gateway run run in small batch and each batch execute in less than 30s.
When I use map state, I still get service unavailable error, though some of the batches passed and some fail.
can anyone guide me api-gateway timeout 30s will not work even we run in map state?

[image]

here two execution passed and two failed
[image]

Comment: Below are the API Gateway Quotas and Limits. You can check and configure it accordingly. For some of the types like REST API its 29 seconds
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html